# status tab not displayed in ui (resque-status)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I am using resque status. In my `Gemfile` I have

```
gem 'resque-status'
```

In `resque_conf.rb` I have

```
require 'resque/status_server'
```

And I open the ui of resque using

```
resque-web ~/resque_conf.rb
```

In `resque.rb` I have

```
 require 'resque/job_with_status'

config = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/redis.yml"))[Rails.env]
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => config['host'], :port => config['port'])

Resque::Status.expire_in = (24 * 60 * 60) # 24hrs in seconds
```

I don't know what I am missing here. When I first set up the resque-status the tab "Statuses" was being displayed but now after about a month it does not show the "Statuses" tab. Anyone got idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `require 'resque/status_server'` from `resque_conf.rb` to `resque.rb`

```
# config/initializers/resque.rb
require 'resque/status_server'
require 'resque/job_with_status'
...
```

Now, fire `> resque-web` and you'll get Statuses tab.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I have been trying to find documentation on how to pass a config file to resque-web that has been mounted inside of rails.